# What should I do with HTTP Status 202?

Tags: json, vb.net, web-services, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm working on a project that have some web service. I'm implementing **CORS** (Cross-origin resource sharing) in this project.
I can't find any solution that can help me with my issue.

I've tried with **Non-CORS** project, and it got no problem, it returned HTTP Status **200** instead of **202**.

What should I do?

This is the picture of the result in postman **implementing CORS**
[image]

This is the picture of the result in postman **Non-CORS**
[image]

Need your help....

Comment: On the server side define the allowed origins: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for all origins. Read more in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Also, status 202 doesn't mean it'll fail. It just means the request was accepted. Are you getting it and stops or are you letting processing continue after that response?

Comment: i've tried to use that before, but i changed from "*" to "specific domain". And it's ok. I think the problem is not about origin anymore. Thanks btw dude

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim , thats the point, i don't know how to let the process continue, so let's say the process is in pending state. (that's why i got no data returned from the webservice, because the process is pending)